# Hibernate envers get deleted row data

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

In my application, I need to show what rows were deleted.
I need to find deleted row details of a particular class.

So far I got a query that returns deleted entity id, how do I get all entity fields?

```
final AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Partner.class, false, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.DEL));
final List<?> results = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you have is what you want, but the issue is that by default Envers doesn't capture the state of the entity when a record is deleted.  The only information captured by default is the revision, revision type, and the primary key values of the entity.

What you need is to set `org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete` to `true` in your hibernate configuration so that not only will it store the values of the entity I mentioned above, but all audited fields.  That will allow the query you are using to return an entity instance with all audited fields populated based on what the entity looked like right before deletion.